# Parsing of duration with HowardHinnant C++ date

Tags: c++, date

Is it possible to use the library https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date to parse duration like 'PT6M2S' and how in such case?

I have tried for instance:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   using namespace date;
   using namespace std::chrono;
   std::istringstream in{"PT6M"};
   minutes tp;
   in >> parse("%X", tp);    
   if (in.fail() || in.bad())
       std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
   else if (in.bad())
       std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
   else
       std::cout << tp << std::endl;
}
```

This give a "fail" when executed.

Comment: What results did **you** get when you tried to do that? Could you share the code you used to do it?

Comment: One assumes you've read the documentation: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#duration_io ? What does "PT" mean? Presumably M and S means minutes and seconds?

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation without understanding how, or even if it's supported, to use it for the duration in ISO8601 format  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Answer (score 1):

`%X` is a locale-dependent *date* (timepoint), not a period. There is no alternative flag either - dates are moments in time, periods are intervals in time. It's simply outside the scope of this date library.

Comment: Ok, then I have to find another library. Any proposal what can be used (if not writing it myself according to other posts here)? Thanks anyway.